# How to get javascript and jQuery variable in code behid in asp.net C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want `otdval` at code behind in asp.net C#

```
otdval = (parseFloat(otdval) + parseFloat(saletax)); // duesignmain;
$("#lblotd").text(String(Math.round(otdval)).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g,"$1,"));
```

Comment: You have two options. Ajax or Submit the form..

Answer (score 2):

Store `otdval` variable value in hidden field and retrieve in code behind.

In aspx create a hidden field

```
<asp:HiddenField id="hdnField" runat="server" />
```

In JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('hdnField').value = otdval;
```

In JQuery

```
$('input:hidden[id*=hdnField]').val(otdval);
```

In Codebhind

```
string otdvalValue = hdnField.Value;
```